# JetPack Compose way of dealing with callbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am coming back to Android development after quite a few years, and things seem to have changed a lot. Apologies in advance if my question is trivial.

Back in the day, we could implement a listener in an `Activity` to be called when a request was complete. Take, for instance, requesting location, or a sensor value. We would implement the appropriate listener interface and get a callback, and we could easily update the UI by going through the inflated XML hierarchy.

This approach seems to have been deprecated in favor of JetPack Compose UI. I have been trying to find a simple example of a very simple task with Compose UI in which an instance of `SensorEventListener` updates the UI every time its `onSensorChanged()` method is called. Unfortunately, all the examples I find request sensor values only when the user taps a button. Considering the fact that Google is favoring JetPack Compose over XML inflated user interface, I don't want to go down the XML path.

Let's say I have the below activity. How do I update the text in Greeting composable when `onSensorChanged()` is called? I don't think calling `setContent` is the way to go.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), SensorEventListener {
    private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        val stepSensor = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
        sensorManager?.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault)

        setContent {
            WearApp("Android")
        }
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        val totalSteps = event!!.values[0]
        // how to update the text from here?
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
        // don't care
    }
}

@Composable
fun WearApp(greetingName: String) {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            TimeText()
            Greeting(greetingName = greetingName)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(greetingName: String) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        text = stringResource(R.string.hello_world, greetingName)
    )
}

@Preview(device = Devices.WEAR_OS_SMALL_ROUND, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    WearApp("Preview Android")
}
```

Comment: What I would do: Subclass `AndroidViewModel`, implement `SensorEventListener` there, register the sensor listener using `init` block, declare and use the step counts as `MutableStateFlow<Float>` which will be updated in `onSensorChanged`, `collectAsState` the state flow of step counts in the `Greeting()` composable, and finally, set the step count value to the `Text` composable. Optionally, unregister the sensor listener in `onCleared` in the view model.

Comment: @Jay I can follow what you're saying, except for `collectAsState` step. Could I bother you with writing `Greeting()` the way you explained it?

Comment: I apologize that I recommended the wrong API -- instead of `collectAsState`, we should use `collectAsStateWithLifeCycle` as it is lifecycle-aware. Please refer [collectAsStateWithLifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/compose/package-summary#extension-functions).

Comment: i don't feel like you have enough knowledge to attempt this, you're starting in the wrong place. instead of worrying about the callbacks and modifying your existing project, understand compose first. write an app with a button that updates text as you tap on it with compose. once you have an understanding of that, take that knowledge to your problem here

Comment: @a_local_nobody you might be right. I tried that, with a button updating text. However, it might not have been the correct JetPack Compose UI way. I wish there was a "best practices" tutorial or something available besides the simplistic CodeLab tutorials.

Comment: there's very rarely a singular correct way of doing anything. if you're able to understand declarative UI to the point where you can update a button, then this should be no different. you're using `setContent` with `WearApp("Android")`. so, you're passing a value to a composable, right ? why can't you pass the values of the callbacks to your composable ? you could have a viewmodel or an observable and your composable could observe on to the changes that you set from your activity ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody ilI thought the call to `setContent` is expensive? Doesn't it remove and recreate all the content? That's why I was asking about the mechanism designers of JetPack Compose UI had envisioned for showing values from system services on the UI.

Comment: but would you need to call setContent multiple times ? i don't think so ? you can have it set your composables and then the composables need to observe on to changes coming from live data in a viewmodel ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody my bad. I thought you meant to call `setContent` from my callback implementation.

Comment: no, i don't think you would, but i'm not sure, i would try to just call setContent and have the composables listen to changes from a VM. my questions are not meant to be sarcastic or offensive, i'm genuinely asking if there's a problem with this that i can't see, hopefully it came across that way

Comment: @a_local_nobody yeah I totally get what you're trying to say. There is no problem besides me not having enough experience with JetPack. Please tell me if I understand correctly. We create a ViewModel descendant in the activity, and pass it as a parameter to each composable like `Greeting()` as a parameter. These composables then _observe_ this vm for changes, while the activity updates it in callbacks?

Comment: @iManBiglari yes, pretty much that sums up the MVVM for composables. it is also known as state hoisting.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your clarification. If only they hadn't come up with a new name for an existing architecture.